'To + noun' as object, complement, or adverbial?
In the sentence ' I gave the book to my brother' or in the sentence ' The teacher gave homework to the students',what specific roles do the prepositional phrases 'to my brother ' and ' to the students' serve? Are they direct objects of their respective verbs, or adverbial phrases or object complements?

Please try to write a title that summarises the content of your post.  "English Grammar" doesn't help me know what the question is.

This question would be better if you explained why you have a doubt.  Perhaps you could include what your text book says about "direct objects" etc.

The word gave has different meanings there. One meaning is "to present a physical object to a person so that they may take it from you" and the other is "to assign a task or issue a command":  The captain gave his platoon an order.    Is it that difference that is causing confusion for you?  If so, the prepositional phrases  indicate the recipient in either meaning, the recipient of the physical object or the recipient of the task or command.

'I gave the book to my brother' is an example of the "dative shift". It is a vestige of Old English, which had clearly defined grammatical cases.
(You can see parallels to this in Modern German:
Ich gab das Buch [der [dative determiner]] Mary.
Ich gab das Buch zu [preposition controlling the dative] Mary.)
As you will see from the link,
I gave the book to Mary and I gave Mary the book are semantically identical. Both were used in Old English.
Grammatically, and if you believe the dative case still exists in English, then "to Mary" is a prepositional phrase. It is an adverbial and Mary is in the dative.)
Whereas, on its own, "Mary"(dative)" is a complement.
However, in some grammars, "Mary" is considered an indirect object.
It is worth considering
I went to London
*I went London
In which "to London" is adverbial.

+1. We have few dative case markers in modern English, which has become an analytical language, for the most part, relying heavily on prepositional phrases for the dative, and word-order for the accusative.

It can't be a direct object, since the direct object is "the book".  It can't be an object complement, since it doesn't tell you what the object is.  Object complements rename or describe objects.
It's a prepositional phrase licenced by the verb "give", and it tells you the recipient of the book. I suppose you could call it "adverbial" but that is such a big and vague category, I'm not sure how you'd use that fact.
